# An unhandled exception of type 'WatiN.Core.Exceptions.RunScriptException' occurred in WatiN.Core.dll

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015, watin

An unhandled exception of type 'WatiN.Core.Exceptions.RunScriptException' occurred in WatiN.Core.dll Additional information: RunScript failed ....can anybody give solution to this error ???

```
browser.GoTo("http://www.errajatsharma.com/invoice/");
browser.TextField(Find.ByName("email")).TypeText("wolverine.rajat@gmail.com");            
browser.TextField(Find.ByName("password")).TypeText("98983662634");
browser.Div(Find.ByName("submit")).Click();
```

i m getting the above error when the debugger reaches typetext event...can anybody help me please ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i ws using  a wrong version version of internet explorer...watin supports IE 6,7 and 8 version only...now i m using firefox version 2.0  ...and upto 3.6 version is supported in watin ...That's why It was giving error in watin.core.dll...Rest of the code is same....anyways Thanks for ur help buddy  !! :)

Comment: can u suggest me some sites on which i can perform watin testing ??

Comment: Could you please accept the answer please? It will help other to pinpoint the same problem you were having. You have millions of websites to play with. To start I will use google and search something, then parse the results and even open some of the results and look for something you are interested in to get used to it. I've used Watin with up to version 9 of IE and it worked just fine (with some issues when running dynamic JS but that is very specific) There are TONs of things you can do with Watin. You can also take a look ad Selenium for browser automation also.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after your edit this makes more sense now. The code you posted seems to be your whole code. In between this line:

```
browser.GoTo("http://www.errajatsharma.com/invoice/");
```

and this lines

```
browser.TextField(Find.ByName("email")).TypeText("wolverine.rajat@gmail.com");
```

browser.TextField(Find.ByName("password")).TypeText("98983662634");

the program needs to wait until the page loads (think about it, that web page might take 4 seconds to load, 1 second, 2 minutes, etc.) to do that wait (whatever time that is) watin has the following code:

```
browser.WaitForComplete();
```

So by adding this line of code in between:

```
browser.GoTo("http://www.errajatsharma.com/invoice/");
browser.WaitForComplete();                                                                                  
browser.TextField(Find.ByName("email")).TypeText("wolverine.rajat@gmail.com");
browser.TextField(Find.ByName("password")).TypeText("98983662634");
browser.Div(Find.ByName("submit")).Click();
```

If that's your issue you should be able to login now with those credentials (I just tried but those credentials aren't real so you need to replace them with your real login details).

EDIT:

Try this:

```
browser.GoTo("http://www.errajatsharma.com/invoice/");
browser.WaitForComplete();                                                                                  
TextField email = browser.TextField(Find.ByName("email"));
if(email.Exists){
  email.TypeText("wolverine.rajat@gmail.com");
}else{
  MessageBox.Show("Can't find email textbox");
}
```

if you still get the message "Can't find email textbox" then the email is not on that page. You can also try

```
email.Value = "Something@something.com";
```

EDIT 2:

I just ran this code:

```
browser.GoTo("http://www.errajatsharma.com/invoice/");
browser.WaitForComplete();              browser.TextField(Find.ByName("email")).TypeText("wolverine.rajat@gmail.com");               browser.TextField(Find.ByName("password")).TypeText("98983662634");
browser.Button(Find.ByName("submit")).Click();
```

And ran as expected (the only difference is that you were clicking on the DIV (named submit) instead of the button (named also submit) inside the DIV). If this still fails you are having some other issue (try newer IE version, etc.)

Comment: i have already tried this " browser.WaitForComplete(); "....but still the exceptiion occurs...do u have any other idea ??? and please tell me asap

Comment: and i have posted fake credentials over here i know ....

Comment: did that work for you?

Comment: no it didn't worked ....do u have any other idea ?

Comment: What have you tried? What is your environment? The more information you can provide the better will be to help you.